# In VSCode, how can I replace text with file information?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I'd like to replace a particular string, say `x`, across a directory with the name of the file in which that string appears. Can I do this from the search menu? If not, is there an extension I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple python script like this to loop through a directory use regex to get the files you want to change and then change them to what you want.

```
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('C:/Users/user/Pictures')

files = []
for x in p.iterdir(): 
    a = re.search('.*(jpe?g|png)',str(x))
    if a is not None:
        files.append(a.group())
        old_file_name = a.group()
        new_file_name = newname
        os.rename(old_file_name, new_file_name)
```